# How to create PayPal subscription form with billing address?

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, subscription, paypal-subscriptions

I am trying to create a PayPal subscription form with billing address but it doesn't work, I'm unable to figure out  the problem, please have a look at this form.

```
<form name="_xclick" action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/webscr" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick-subscriptions" />
    <input type="hidden" name="business" value="business.account@test.com" />
    <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD" />
    <input type="hidden" name="no_shipping" value="1" />

    <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Baseball Hat Monthly" />
    <input type="hidden" name="item_number" value="123" />
    <input type="hidden" name="a3" value="5.00" />
    <input type="hidden" name="p3" value="3" />
    <input type="hidden" name="t3" value="M" />
    <input type="hidden" name="src" value="1" />
    <input type="hidden" name="sra" value="1" />

    <input type="hidden" name="return" value="http://www.example.com/thankyou" />
    <input type="hidden" name="cancel_return"  value="http://www.example.com/cancel" />
    <input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value="http://www.example.com/ipn" />

    <input type="hidden" value="Colorado Springs" name="city" id="city">
    <input type="hidden" value="US" name="country" id="country">
    <input type="hidden" value="personal.account@test.com" name="email" id="email">
    <input type="hidden" value="Tahir" name="first_name" id="first_name">
    <input type="hidden" value="Yasin" name="last_name" id="last_name">
    <input type="hidden" value="80903" name="zip" id="zip">
    <input type="hidden" value="CO" name="state" id="state">
    <input type="hidden" value="219 W. Colorado Avenue Suite 200" name="address1" id="address1">
    <input type="hidden" value="" name="address2" id="address2">
    <input type="hidden" value="1" name="address_override" id="address_override">


    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Subscribe" />
</form>
```

You can see `address_override` attribute is set to `1` but when I see the order detail in my PayPal business account, it doesn't show me the submitted address but shows following notice.

[image: PayPal notice]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you have "no_shipping=1" set you aren't requiring a shipping address for the transaction so that is why the address doesn't appear during the checkout process and in the transaction details.

I changed it to both "2" and "0" but the address didn't appear after I logged into a test account - like it should. If I switch the button type to be "_xclick" with "no_shipping=2" the address does appear correctly.

I'll file a ticket with the engineers to get this resolved for Subscription buttons.

Comment: Thank you so much! just changed `no_shipping` value to `2` and it started working.

Comment: Although I am overriding the address by setting `address_override` to `1` but still it takes the address that is registered on PayPal, can you tell me how to get address from this form? I'm sure you can help :)

Comment: Aye, it not pulling the address you're passing over is what I created the bug for. If you want to keep up on it create a ticket at PayPal.com/mts, give me the ticket number, and I'll nab it.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, here is Ticket#130604-000416

Comment: thank you very much, just got a reply via PayPal, can you please also check this one Ticket#130604-000417

Comment: can you please update me about this bug (Ticket#130604-000416), as it still doesn't work.

Comment: thanks for the update via email, can you please tell me how can I get billing address for subscriptions from users?